# Math calculations in java

Tags: java, android

Is there an easy way(instead of hard coding) to display intermidiate calculation in java?
For example: x+y*3= 10+15*3=55
I have searching for an answer without success.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Output to the console? Make it available for inspection in debugging?

Comment: Do you want to display it on screen after some kind of event?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x = 10;
  int y = 15;
  System.out.printf("x+y*3 = %d+%d*3 = %d", x, y, (x + (y * 3)));
}
```

Which outputs

```
x+y*3 = 10+15*3 = 55
```

here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn parsing strings as shown here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87